# Can not add access rules with WellKnownSidType.WorldSid on windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, access-rules

Here is the code:

```
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
var directorySecurity = new DirectorySecurity();
directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(this.PathToSettings.LocalPath), directorySecurity);
var fileSecurity = new FileSecurity();
fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
using (var fs = new FileStream(this.PathToSettings.LocalPath, FileMode.Create,     FileSystemRights.FullControl, FileShare.None, 1024, FileOptions.None, fileSecurity))
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Resources.DefaultSettings);
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

The problem: on windows 7 these access rules does not apply to file (I do not see group `Everyone` on `Security` page of the file properties dialog.

I want to allow access to specified file for everyone (admins, users, whatever).

What I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: I know this is old, but the very first line of your question answered mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a class that saves settings - it removes old file and creates new (using default security rules). Very stupid, don't know why someone wrote such code.